# Jena ontology API

Tags: rdf, sparql, jena, ontology, protege

I'm new to Jena and Protégé.  I did some stuff with these. I have some problems:

1. Do I need to use SPARQL query to get the ontology classes, subclasses, properties, and values, or can I do it with OWL-api? Can you show me how?
2. How do I get the data property values?
3. How do I load the ontology that is defined in my local machine and access the classes?

Answer (score 2):

The Jena Ontology API is great for getting individual classes, properties, and their details and relationships.

SPARQL queries are great for querying a large number of instances and filter out only the bits of information (including their property values) that you need.

For your other questions, reading a bit of the documentation might help! The answers are in here:

- [Intro to RDF and Jena](http://jena.apache.org/tutorials/rdf_api.html)
- [Ontology API](http://jena.apache.org/documentation/ontology/index.html)
- [I/O Quick Intro](http://jena.apache.org/documentation/io/index.html)

Comment: thanks for your reply:::

i do some stuff with protege and got the RDFS file, not owl file.. which file will be best for query with sparql.how do  i read the property values? i faced lot of problems with getting the property values... can u show me the way::
in my rdf file there is no URI...how can i query with it or are there any way to get the URI ?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

The [jena-examples](https://github.com/castagna/jena-examples) project on on GitHub demostrates [some use cases of the API](https://github.com/castagna/jena-examples/tree/master/src/main/java/org/apache/jena/examples).

Answer (score 0):

Yup jena-fuseki server can be used to query ontology classes,subclasses,properties and values.
Download apache jena-fuseki server
Next we import this ontology to Apache’s Jena Fuseki server and run some simple SPARQL queries.
Execute the following command in command prompt:
$ ./ fuseki −server −−update −−mem / ds
If everything goes well, we should have our server running at:
http://localhost:3030/
web browser go to http://localhost:3030/
a)Choose control panel then select "/ds" source.
b) Upload the file ".owl file” upload it to server
c) Now d) To Query triples go to SPARQL query and run it.
d) Your database is filled with triples.